# Why isn't my component re-rendering or my mapstatetoprops not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a simple React Native app with Redux.

- When I try to connect my application state to my redux state, **it is working.**
- But when I map my redux state to the props, it is **not** working.

My redux-dev-tools is giving me a full state.

If I log my props, its empty

**Versions**

- react: "16.6.3",
- react-native: "^0.57.1",
- react-redux: "^6.0.1"
- redux: "^4.0.1"

```js
//index.js

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import reducers from './src/reducers/index.js';

const store = createStore(reducers, {}, devToolsEnhancer({ realtime: true }));

const AppContainer = () => {
    return (
        <Provider store={store} >
            <App />
        </Provider>
    )
}
```

```
//App.js

import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { setAccounts } from './src/actions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('state', state);
  return {
    accountArray: state.bankReducer.accountArray,
  }
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { setAccounts})(class App extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
   const accounts = new Date().getTime();
   this.props.setAccounts(accounts);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('New accounts array has been received', nextProps.accountArray);
  }
```

```
//index.js ../reducers

import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import bankReducer from './bankReducer';

export default combineReducers({
    bankReducer: bankReducer,
})
```

```
//bankReducer.js

import { ACCOUNTS_SET } from '../actions/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    accountArray: [],
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ACCOUNTS_SET:
        console.log('hello2');
            return { ...state, accountArray: action.payload }
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

```
//bankActions.js

import { ACCOUNTS_SET} from './actionTypes';

export const setAccounts = (accounts) => {

    console.log('hello2');

    return {
        type: ACCOUNTS_SET,
        payload: accounts
    }
};


my console [1]

I expect to have an accountsArray with value 2 in my props after I do mapStateToProps. 
The value of accountsArray stays empty


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENT8Y.png
```

Comment: You're not going to have a new value of accountsArray ... untill you call and action with type `ACCOUNTS_SET `

Comment: I did not upload it here.

Comment: You have to call this action somewhere in your code ... for you to receive a new set of props through your `mapStateToProps` function ... if you did already ... plz share that piece of code along with how to wire up your `combineReducers`

Comment: sorry, forgot to upload my componentDidMount

Comment: have your tried the console log in `componentWillReceiveProps` I mentioned in my post ?

Comment: I applied all your changes but it's still not working. The log with the the received props is not even showing

Comment: that mean you're not receiving **any NEW props** ... you're passing static values like 4 and 1 ... which could be cached ... try to call your action with some dynamic value for testing like `new Date().getTime()` ... and force reloading your app in the simulator through the emulator menu for your component to be unmounted and re-mounted

Comment: the console.log is still not showing. but what do you mean with force reloading?

Comment: I mean not to depend on `hot loading` ... use `reload` action in the developer menu of your emulator ... and put a console log in your action isself to make sure it's actually called

Comment: I mean to put a console.log inside `case ACCOUNTS_SET` and `setAccounts` action-function

Comment: I have added an image of my console

Comment: The only way avaliable for me to help ... is to upload your sample on github to check

Comment: https://github.com/MaximWuyts/reduxIssueRN

Comment: I just download the src code on my machine and run it (I haven't touched a single line of code) ... and here's the console result :)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ESK_kfkT86neM5iuuBgocf2VWonY_E4I

Comment: fml :p how is that possible

Comment: have you tested it on android or ios?

Comment: On ios i got an error .. on android worked

Answer (score 1):

You already have your action ... you need to call it somewhere in your code ... for you to receive a new set of props through your `mapStateToProps` function

**Second**

Second param to `createStore` is the `preloadedState`, and third is any enhancers you want to have:

```
const store = createStore(reducers, {} , devToolsEnhancer({ realtime: true }));
```

**Example**

```
import { setAccounts } from 'your/path/to/actions/js-file';

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Example calling your action:
    const accounts = 'your values';
    this.props.setAccounts(accounts);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('New accounts array has been received', nextProps.accountArray);
  }

  render() {
    //
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  console.log('state', state);
  return {
    accountArray: state.bankReducer.accountArray,
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { setAccounts },
)(App);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce the issue by running the demo project you published on Github: https://github.com/MaximWuyts/reduxIssueRN

I got it working by downgrading react-redux to v5. So I assume it's a dependency problem/mismatch.

It worked after running:

- `npm i react-redux@5`
- `react-native start --reset-cache`